# Ctrl+Click using WebDriver

Tags: webdriver

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858699/how-to-simulate-ctrlclick-with-watir-webdriver) concerning Watir-WebDriver.

What is the best way to do Ctrl+click on a DOM element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Google search of "webdriver ctrl click"](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=webdriver%20ctrl%20click) turned up this result:

Ctrl+click requires three actions: a send_keys action to press the CTRL key, then a click action, and then another send_keys action to release the CTRL key.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm confused about is that `send_keys` is done *with respect to an element* (i.e. `element.send_keys`). What `element` should I choose here?

Comment: The wording of the original question suggests you already have an element in mind.  Are you asking how to identify that element to Webdriver?

Comment: Well the element to do the click on is determined. But there is no specific element listening to the "Ctrl" event.

Comment: The answer may depend upon which event propagation model you use, but I believe you can direct the CTRL key press/release to the body element.

Answer (score 0):

for clicking on the link which expected to be opened from new tab use this

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
driver.get("https://www.yourSite.com"); 
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("path_to_link")); 

Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL) 
       .click(element) 
       .keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL) 
       .build() 
       .perform(); 

ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles()); 
driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use Actions which is described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756532/how-to-hold-key-down-with-selenium

You will want to execute the key_down action (for the CONTROL key), then the click action, then the key_up action.

The key codes for non-letter keys are listed here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains

Answer (score -1):

The element is nothing but the variable to find the properties of the object so we are using WebElement to find it

```
WebElement obj = findElement(By.Xpath("")).click(); 
obj.sendkeys("xxxxx");
```

If you guys want to click submit button  you can use code `obi.submit()`. This code navigates to the next page. It acts as the button `click()`.